# vb.net winforms datetimepicker - change font colors of disabled dates

Tags: vb.net

On my datetimepicker I set the maxdate to today's dates. The font color of the days in the next month is gray but the days in the current month that is disabled still shows as black.

Is there a way to change change the font color of all disabled days to gray.

Thank you

Hendriette

Comment: are you setting a mindate? If I set a maxdate of today and a mindate of 2/15/19, All dates outside that range are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTimePicker.MaxDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to sets the maximum date and time that can be selected in the control.

Using `DateTimePicker1.MaxDate = Date.Today` automatically hide future dates without the necessity to disable them.

For example, with `Date.Today` = 2019/02/26:

[image: max date]

Comment: I do set the MaxDate. It disables all the future dates but still show's the days in the current month, does not hide them like your example. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Tested with `VS2015` and `.Net Framework 4.6.1` and everything works like in my answer even if I set `MaxDate` property from designer.
Try adding a `DateTimePicker` with `MaxDate` property in a new `Form` to see what happens.